# Pivot one table without using pivot keyword

Tags: sql, pivot, pivot-table

I have a source data.
Input
|Policyname| amount |type|
|----------|--------|----|
|PN1       |100     |P1  |
|PN2       |200     |P2  |
|PN3       |300     |P3  |
|PN4       |400     |P1  |
|PN1       |500     |P2  |

Output
|Policyname|  P1 |   P2 |  P3 |
|----------|-----|------|-----|
|PN1       | 100 |  500 |     |
|PN2       |     |  200 |     |
|PN3       |     |      | 300 |
|PN4       | 400 |      |     |

How can I get this out without using pivot keyword

I tried using pivot and it will work.but I want using a single query without pivot keyword

Comment: Conditional aggregation?

Comment: Don't tag conflicting products, just tag the (R)DBMS you are *really* using.

Answer (score 1):

This has been asked and answered about a million times. Conditional aggregation is the solution. Since you posted sample data and desired output I figured you deserve an answer instead of closing as a duplicate.

```
declare @Something table
(
    Policyname char(3)
    , amount int
    , type char(2)
)
insert @Something values
('PN1', 100, 'P1')
, ('PN2', 200, 'P2')
, ('PN3', 300, 'P3')
, ('PN4', 400, 'P1')
, ('PN1', 500, 'P2')

select s.Policyname
    , p1 = sum(case when s.type = 'P1' then amount end)
    , p2 = sum(case when s.type = 'P2' then amount end)
    , p3 = sum(case when s.type = 'P3' then amount end)
from @Something s
group by s.Policyname
order by s.Policyname
```

Comment: Good answer. A million times is probably an understatement :)